# How to target the basket value only in a div with multiple values

Tags: javascript, regex, if-statement, currency

I've got a piece of code where i want to target the basket total only and if the amount is more then €40 i want it to print a string to state this or if its under the amount then to print something else.

The issue i have is the div that wraps around the total basket amount states the number of items that are in your basket as well. I can't change the existing code on the cart so is there a way i can target the basket price in this div only?

```js
var patternPrice = /[^0-9\.]/g;  
var targetBasketTotal = document.querySelector('.cart');
var totalAmount = parseFloat(targetBasketTotal.textContent.replace(patternPrice, "")) / 100;
console.log(totalAmount);

if(totalAmount < 40) {
  targetBasketTotal.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<section class='message'>Basket is less then €40</section>");
} else {
  targetBasketTotal.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<section class='message'>Basket is more then €40</section>");
}
```

```html
<div class="cart">10 items | €&nbsp;38,87</div>
```

Comment: I recommend not to fowllow up on that approach. If you can not change the markup of the basked and/or not access the plain data somehow I would rather ask the person who is responsible for the markup to output those values as data attributes or in any other way. Parsing values from HTML markup is a pain and very unreliable. Especially over time. They could change and/or localise the HTML structure anytime which leads to your entire script failing. It might seem like a neat quick solution right now, but you can be sure that it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split` with your replace for select just price like:

```js
var patternPrice = /[^0-9\.]/g;  
var targetBasketTotal = document.querySelector('.cart');
var totalAmount = parseFloat(targetBasketTotal.textContent.split('|')[1].replace(patternPrice, "")) / 100;
console.log(totalAmount);

if(totalAmount < 40) {
  targetBasketTotal.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<section class='message'>Basket is less then €40</section>");
} else {
  targetBasketTotal.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<section class='message'>Basket is more then €40</section>");
}
```

```html
<div class="cart">10 items | €&nbsp;38,87</div>
```

Reference:

- [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

PS. Obviously the structure must be the same

Comment: Ah yes, this is exactly what i was looking for thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome, remember the best way is change html, this is just a tricky solution. Please approve answer :)